# How to aggregate strings and separate them with comma in Java?

Tags: java, concatenation

I am very new to Java, but I would like to be able to easily aggregate the following input (two columns):

```
one a
one b
two a
two c
three a
three b
three c
```

into the following output (two columns):

```
one a,b
two a,c
three a,b,c
```

So for each word in the first column, I would like to obtain a list of comma-separated words. 
Is there any simple way I can do it in Java?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use some thing like HashMap<key, value>

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch well I guess I'm stuck at the very beginning. There is lots of information how to split strings into my input format, but not much how to aggregate/concatenate into strings. I've tried StringUtils.join(column2, ",") but it doesn't work if I want to aggregate for each word in column 1. I'm guessing some sort of looping may work, but unfortunately my skills in Java are not great.

Comment: You can aggregate strings using the "+" operator (concatenation). See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html .

Comment: @Lawrence, which he should be able to do if he only googled it :( good forbid that you start learning java on the Oracle site :((

Answer (score 1):

There are a whole bunch of ways to accomplish this task with Java but I'm going to show you how to do it using a pattern matcher with a small regex expression string.

The code below may look pretty large for what it does but if you remove all the comments you will find that it's quite small. The work horse for this is within the method named SetAggregateList() and as I have previously mentioned it is extensively commented so that you know what was done. Just load it up and run it then look at your output console (panel) for the final list results.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * @author DevilsHnd
 */
public class AggregateList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* This string array contains our so called two word strings. How these 
           strings get into the array is up to you.  */
        String[] sArray = {"one a","one b","two a","two c","three a","three b","three c"};

        /* Declare and establish an ArrayList variable. This ArrayList will
           ultimately hold our aggregate strings.  */
        ArrayList<String> aggregateStrings = new ArrayList<>();

        //Okay...let's fire things up and fill our ArrayList with
        // aggregate strings.
        SetAggregateList(aggregateStrings, sArray);

        // Now that we've filled out ArrayList let's iterate through
        // it and display the contents of each list element.
        for (int i = 0; i < aggregateStrings.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(aggregateStrings.get(i));
        }    

    }

    private static void SetAggregateList(ArrayList<String> arrayList, String[] sArray) {
        /* We start by iterating (looping) through our two word strings held 
           within the sArray[] string array.  */
        for (int i = 0; i < sArray.length; i++) {

            /* We place the array element into a string variable
               named element so that we don't need to reference
               the index all the time.  */
            String element = sArray[i];

            /* We establish yet two more string variables so as
               to hold each word contained within each array element
               as we iterate through the array.  */
            String word1 = "", word2 = "";

            /* To fill the word1 and word2 string variables we're 
               going to use the Pattern Matcher method and a small 
               regex expression for obtaining the '2nd' word and 
               beyond.
               Here we establish our pattern to use and place it into
               a variable conveniently named pattern....  */
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\s([a-z]+)");
            /* Breakdown of the expression string above: "(?i)\\s([a-z]+)"
            (?i)    ignore letter case.
            \\s     start from the first space encountered.
            (       group start...
            [a-z]   accept only letters from a to z (or A to Z because we ignore
                    case) after the space that was encountered.
            +       Match one or more of the previous item which in this case is 
                    the [a-z].
            )       group end. Group start & group end establishes what is called 
                    Group 1.  */

            /* We now run the pattern through the matcher method to
               see if there is a match to our regex expression.  */
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(element);

            // See if the matcher method finds a match to our expression.
            if (matcher.find()) {
                /* it does so place that group string into our word2 variable 
                   but trim any leading or trailing spaces from it first.  */
                word2 = matcher.group(1).trim();
                /* Now that we have the second section of the string contained
                   in the array element we can easily extract the first section
                   by removing the space and 2nd string section from the array 
                   element. And to make sure there are no leading or trailing
                   spaces, we trim it as well.   */           
                word1 = element.replace(" " + word2,"").trim();
            }

            /* This boolean variable is simply used as a flag to inform the iteration 
               process that the first word in a array element we are processing is 
               already contained within our aggregateStrings ArrayList. This way we
               ensure singularity (no duplicates).   */
            boolean haveIt = false;

            /* Here is the crunch of it all. We now need to iterate through our 
               ArrayList we've created to see if we have already placed the first 
               word of the string Array element we are currently processing into
               the list. If it isn't then we add it but if it is then we need to 
               check the second word (string section) and compare it to the second
               word from our string array element and see if that is also already 
               contained within the list for that first word. If it isn't then we
               add it to the first word but first applying a comma to delimit it
               from any other 2nd words we have previously added.  */

            // Iterate through the aggregateStrings ArrayList...
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j++) {

                /* We place the ArrayList element into a string variable
                   named aElement so that we don't need to reference
                   the index all the time.  */
                String aElement = arrayList.get(j);

                /* We establish yet two more string variables so as to
                   hold each word contained within each ArrayList element
                   as we iterate through the ArrayList.  */
                String alWord1 = "", alWord2 = "";

                /* To fill the alWord1 and alWord2 string variables we're 
                   going to use the Pattern Matcher method yet again and a
                   small regex expression for obtaining the '2nd' word and 
                   beyond. This expression is a little different than the
                   one we used earlier, if you look closely you can see that
                   we have added a comma (,) in our matches section of the 
                   expression [a-z,]. We need to do this because as we are
                   developing our aggregate strings we are adding commas for
                   delimiters between all our second words. We want to accept
                   these during our Pattern Match for separating the two 
                   string sections for comparisons.
                   Here we establish our pattern to use and place it into
                   a variable named aPattern....  */
                Pattern aPattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\s([a-z,]+)");
                /* Breakdown of the expression string above: "(?i)\\s([a-z]+)"
                   (?i)    ignore letter case.
                   \\s     start from the first space encountered.
                   (       group start...
                   [a-z,]  accept only letters from a to z (or A to Z because we ignore
                           case) and commas after the space that was encountered.
                   +       Match one or more of the previous item which in this case is 
                           the [a-z,].
                   )       group end. Group start & group end establishes what is called 
                           Group 1.  */

                /* We now run the pattern through the matcher method to
                   see if there is a match to our regex expression.  */
                Matcher aMatcher = aPattern.matcher(aElement);

                // See if the matcher method finds a match to our expression.
                if (aMatcher.find()) {
                    /* it does so place that group string into our alWord2 variable 
                       but trim any leading or trailing spaces from it first.  */
                    alWord2 = aMatcher.group(1).trim();
                    /* Now that we have the second section of the string contained
                       in the ArrayList element we can easily extract the first section
                       by removing the space and 2nd string section from the ArrayList 
                       element. And to make sure there are no leading or trailing
                       spaces, we trim it as well.   */   
                    alWord1 = aElement.replace(" " + alWord2,"").trim();
                }

                /* Here we do our checks. First we compare the first word from our 
                   ArrayList iteration element against the fist word of the string
                   Array iteration...   */
                if (alWord1.equals(word1)) {
                    /* If it's a match then we know that the first word is already
                       contained within the ArrayList so we set our haveIt flag to
                       true so as to ensure the process doesn't add it again.   */
                    haveIt = true;
                    /* Now we need to see if the second word section of the ArrayList
                       already contains the second word from the string Array element
                       currently in process.        */
                    if (!alWord2.contains(word2)) {
                        // It doesn't so add it to the ArrayList element.
                        aElement+= "," + word2; 
                        arrayList.set(j, aElement);
                    }
                }
            }

            /* Here we check to see if our haveIt flag is false and if it is then this
               obviously means that we do not have the String Array element first word
               within our ArrayList so we add it.     */
            if (!haveIt) { arrayList.add(element); }
        }
    }

}
```

I hope this helps you out a little.

Answer (score 0):

1 read the lines

2 use split to split each line, and get first and second element

3 put them in a Map > : search for what in what

4 iterate and show your result